# Carousel displays in atom live preview, however it won't in browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently making a website for my coursework and I'm using the bootstrap carousel to display 3 images as a full browser landing page.

I have JS and JQuery imported and the carousel does show in the atom live-preview package, however, when I try to view it in chrome or firefox it doesn't seem to show.  I can see the next and previous buttons in my header, but no images.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>OFF TEMPO</title>

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:300,600,700|Rubik+Mono+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <!--HEADER-->
    <div id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Website-Logo" height="60px" width="140px"></a>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="home-active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="dj.html">DJ/Producers</a></li>
            <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- FULL VIEW CAROUSEL -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item carousel-item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/nt-applicaple.jpg');"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item carousel-item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/haney.jpg');"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item carousel-item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/Ash.jpg');"></div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
      </a>
    </header>


    <div class="clear"></div>

    <!-- HOME CONTENT -->
    <div class="home-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>HOME</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- FOOTER -->

    <footer>

    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #242424;
    height: auto;
    direction: ltr;
    min-width: 370px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

/* HEADER */

.header-fix {
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    height: 5.4em;
    background-color: rgba(31,31,31,0.95);
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: may be file path issue.try to provide full path of the images there

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it doesn't seem to be the issue, here's some screenshots: https://puu.sh/vGM40/4cade59bf7.jpg https://puu.sh/vGM4K/02feab95ab.png

Comment: The nav should be above the carousel but that's a whole other issue

Comment: I got the issue. instead of setting background image you need to add them  in image src like:- `<div class="item carousel-item">
            <div class="fill"><img src="images/nt-applicaple.jpg"></div>
          </div>`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, however, the carousel now goes past the browser height, know how I can keep it to browser height so all the image is in few then the content is below?

Comment: Like a landing page :)

Comment: you need to have small images in size.Specially height. (something  like banner images\)

Comment: Mkay, I tried reducing them to banner sized images (340px height) but then it stops at 340px and doesn't fill I've reduced them to 864px height, but they're going way over that.

Comment: I assume it's something to do with my fill class or the container being too large?  

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Again it's only doing this in browser, but in atom live view it works as intended https://puu.sh/vGOI6/f25457fc23.jpg

Comment: if you will change width height of your div then images will looks squease and will looks bad . you need to change image as well as div hieght

Comment: How do you mean?  I have reduced the images height and scaled the width accordingly to 864px, however I only want the container to fill the browser and it's currently overflowing past the bottom, like so: https://puu.sh/vGPL2/a0379232cd.jpg

Comment: I want it to be like this https://puu.sh/vGPQb/6da3add6a8.jpg  Thanks for the help btw :)